# Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int php beginner

Tags: php, laravel, sql-update, laravel-5.4, private-functions

please give me some suggestions on how my code will work properly. I am having a loop that gives me an id and quantity to update every loop into my database.

but i got an error when i pass it to my private function and try to execute it. 
I am just a beginner in PHP/Laravel.
Here is my full code:

```
public function updateProduct(Request $request) {
    $ids = array();
        foreach ($request->products as $ship_id) {
            $product_id = DB::table('shipping_products')->select('product_id','quantity')
            ->where(['shipping_products.shipping_id'=>$ship_id])
            ->get();
            array_push($ids,$product_id);
        }

        foreach ($ids as $value) {
            foreach ($value as $update) {
                $this->updateProductQty($update->product_id,$update->quantity);
            }
        }
    }

    private function updateProductQty($product_id, $quantity_order) {
        $qty = DB::table('products')->select('quantity')
            ->where(['products.product_id'=>$product_id])
            ->get();
        $updateTotalQty = $qty - $quantity_order;
        DB::table('products')
            ->where('product_id', $product_id)
            ->update(array(           
            'quantity' => $updateTotalQty
        ));

    }
```

i got an error in this lines:

```
$this->updateProductQty($update->product_id,$update->quantity);
```

it says error message:

```
Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int
```

Comment: What are the declared type of `products` and `quantity` ? I think that `products` is a `CollectionType`

Comment: @YaatSuka thanks for your fast reply. Here is it {#300 ▼
  +"product_id": 1
  +"quantity": 1
} when i dd($update) inside the foreach

Comment: What's the value of `$updateTotalQty` ?

Comment: private function updateProductQty($product_id, $quantity_order) its a function that what i want is just to update my data from database everytime the foreach loop got its data

Comment: Sorry, I talked about the variable at this line: `$updateTotalQty = $qty - $quantity_order;`

Comment: @YaatSuka ops. sorry sir. its a variable where $qty is the quantity of my database from products table and i want it to be deducted by the ordered quantity. and store it in $updateTotalQty data and after storing that is my new quantity that i will update in my database. just like the function that i've posted. after deducting, i want to update it. thats what my function wants

Comment: ok but can you `var_dump()` the value, to be sure that the problem doesn't comes from that variable or its type?

Comment: @YaatSuka i tried this:$updateTotalQty = $qty - $quantity_order;
        var_dump($updateTotalQty); but i cant see the value because i am getting the error whenever i will activate the private function

Answer (score 1):

Try to do that to check if the data is what you're looking for:

```
foreach ($ids as $value) {
        foreach ($value as $update) {
            //$this->updateProductQty($update->product_id,$update->quantity);
            var_dump($update);
            var_dump($update->product_id);
            var_dump($update->quantity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes it is? the $update->product_id gives me what should i want and also the $update->quantity. i think its because they are objects. and my $updateTotalQty is an int?

Comment: object(stdClass)#300 (2) { ["product_id"]=> int(1) ["quantity"]=> int(1) } int(1) int(1) object(stdClass)#299 (2) { ["product_id"]=> int(2) ["quantity"]=> int(1) } int(2) int(1) object(stdClass)#298 (2) { ["product_id"]=> int(1) ["quantity"]=> int(1) } int(1) int(1)

Comment: var_dump($update->product_id); int(1) int(2) int(1) 

var_dump($update->quantity); int(1) int(1) int(1)

Comment: tried this but nothing happens // $updateTotalQty = $qty->quantity - $quantity_order;

Comment: Please, put that on the first line of your private function (before the query):
`var_dump($product_id);die;` and give me the result. I think that one variable is not the type you're looking for: it could be an array or a collection of integers